# How does one separate page content within wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a site for a client and have run into a predicament.

When the client would go to edit a page's content (this site does NOT use posts - just content static site). i want the content to be separated into separate sections, so in this case, it would have separate containers for each section on the page. But the problem is the code below, outputs all of the content within one container.

Now i understand you can edit this in wordpress admin and add the separate divs, but then the issue is, while i can read the code and not swap wordpress editor back to visual mode, my client cannot and will need to swap to visual mode to edit text on pages etc.

How can one achieve this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="width100 widthPC80 centerElement">
      <?php if (have_posts()){ 
                while (have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    the_content(); 
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example the code below:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

becomes

```
&nbsp;Hello World &nbsp;
```

when swapping between visual and text editing mode.

Is there a way to separate the content so it can be edited by the client but not affect formatting.

The closest thing i can think of to it, is this site:
https://www.curse.com/

You can see the different sections (scroll down), each with an image and block of text, is there a way the same affect can be achieved in wordpress?

Comment: You can use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and then you can choose where you want the content from those fields to be displayed within your template.

Comment: there are some plugins that'll make that possible like https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/screenshots/

Comment: I'll take a look thanks. Noticing the downvotes, just want to add, this is not a paid client so i am not profiting off your knowledge, it's a client i'm working for to learn wordpress and they get a site out of it too!

Comment: better to create custom post types  meta boxes if the client is going to be using it, that way you can have a specific template linked to the custom post and your client will not have to worry about getting the field name correct. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes google for tutorials that will show you the whole process and also custom post, and template custom post